# Keyboard Shortcut to Remove Computers from Remote Desktop Connection List

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I previously stumbled upon a keyboard shortcut which allows you to remove Computer Names from the Remote Desktop Connection list, but it only works when you click on the drop down and have the Computer Name highlighted. It did not work when you actually selected the computer name and were brought back into the computer name field.

I know there are other ways of clearing out specific computers in the list, such as through the registry, but I am looking to find the keyboard shortcut.

Does anyone know what the keyboard shortcut for this is? I have tried the obvious ones such as Delete, Backspace, et cetera, with no luck.